# Getting invalid formal parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters

### This is an SO challenge

I would like to know how someone would get an invalid formal parameters in a function without the `arguments` object to as simulate not knowing the format of the parameter destructuring assignment. This is not an ECMAScript question and only pertains to JavaScript.

Your `mySolution` cannot access `arguments` or `test`. You are provided with an `args` array which contains the parameter names. You must return an object which has a property for every parameter which is the parameter that was passed to the function. In short, `results[prop]` must === `test[prop]`. Your solution shouldn't rely on bugs or security holes as they may not be present in the future. The solution to this problem of which I have in mind does not rely on any bugs.

```
(function () {
    function mySolution ({
        var,
        this,
        function,
        if,
        return,
        true
    }) {
        // prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
        var test = arguments = null,

        args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return', 'true'],
        results = {};

        // put your solution here

        return results;
    };
    var test = {
        "var"     : {},
        "this"    : {},
        "function": {},
        "if"      : {},
        "return"  : {},
        "true"    : {}
    },
    results = mySolution(test),
    pass = true;

    for (var prop in test)
        if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            if (results[prop] !== test[prop])
                pass = false;

    alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL")
}());
```

Here's one of the two possible solutions that I would have accepted:

```
(function () {
    function mySolution ({
        var,
        this,
        function,
        if,
        return,
        true
    }) {
        // prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
        var test = arguments = null,

        args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return', 'true'],
        results = {};

        var i = args.length;
        while (i--) {
            results[args[i]] = eval("function::" + args[i]);
            // function::[args[i]] won't work unless you eval() it
        }

        return results;
    };
    var test = {
        "var"     : {},
        "this"    : {},
        "function": {},
        "if"      : {},
        "return"  : {},
        "true"    : {}
    },
    results = mySolution(test),
    pass = true;

    for (var prop in test)
        if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            if (results[prop] !== test[prop])
                pass = false;

    alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL")
}());
```

The solution works by using the default `function::` namespace in combination with `eval()` scope.

For example: `foo.function::bar` and `foo.function::['bar']` are the same thing `foo.bar`.

Comment: i didn't even know you could define functions like that: function f({a, b, c})! what's that all about?

Comment: @nickf: It's part of [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Destructuring_assignment)'s destructuring assignment.

Comment: I dint know about 'function::' thing. Gonna have good time reading about this. Awesome problem btw.

Comment: Ashish: You're going to have a hard time with that as it's not documented anywhere. Heck, I think I'm the only person to ever do as much as to even mention it on MDC. The function:: namespace is not mentioned in the E4X spec. It's main use is for adding methods to XML.prototype. `XML.prototype.x = myFunc` doesn't work but `XML.prototype.function::x = myFunc` does.

Comment: Ashish: If you want to read more I have a blog post about property namespaces in JavaScript 1.6+ that you may want to read: http://eligrey.com/blog/post/namespacing-properties-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks a lot Elijah. I would surely love reading this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 100 points

```
(function () {
    function mySolution ({
        var,
        this,
        function,
        if,
        return,
        true
    }) {
        // prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
        var test = arguments = null,

        args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return', 'true'],
        results = {};

        // put your solution here
        var getEscUnicode = function(str) {
            var ret = "";
            for(var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
                var temp = parseInt(str.charCodeAt(j)).toString(16).toUpperCase();
                for(var i=0; i < 5 - temp.length; i++) {
                    temp = "0" + temp;
                }
                ret = ret + "\\u" + temp;
            }
            return ret;

        }
        for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            results[args[i]] = eval(getEscUnicode(args[i]));
        }
        return results;
    };
    var test = {
        "var"     : {},
        "this"    : {},
        "function": {},
        "if"      : {},
        "return"  : {},
        "true"    : {}
    },
    results = mySolution(test),
    pass = true;

    for (var prop in test)
        if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                if (results[prop] !== test[prop])
                        pass = false;

    alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL")
}());
```

Comment: Congratulations, you actually figured out one of the two possible solutions to the challenge! Your solution relies on what I think is a bug and so if nobody finds the other solution by tomorrow I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tested PASS in FireFox 3.0.13!
I "cheated", by altering the Object prototype:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
(function () {
    function mySolution ({
        var,
        this,
        function,
        if,
        return,
        true
    }) {
        // prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
        var test = arguments = null,

        args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return', 'true'],
        results = {};

        // put your solution here
        Object.prototype._hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty =
function(prop) {
 results[prop] = this[prop];
 return this._hasOwnProperty(prop);
}

        return results;
    };
    var test = {
        "var"     : {},
        "this"    : {},
        "function": {},
        "if"      : {},
        "return"  : {},
        "true"    : {}
    },
    results = mySolution(test),
    pass = true;

    for (var prop in test)
        if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                if (results[prop] !== test[prop])
                        pass = false;

    alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL")
}());

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Put the body of your page below this line -->

<!-- Put the body of your page above this line -->
</body>
</html>
```

Does this count? I guess it probably doesn't. =p

Comment: Also tested in IE7, but the script doesn't work at all (even if I delete my solution and just use the provided code on its own)

Comment: It doesn't count but it sure is a creative solution! I guess I'm going to have to make `results` be `null` to :P

Comment: Do I at least get a vote in case nobody else gets it, since I got the test to pass? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Homework? Here's a hint: use [`eval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp).

Comment: No, this is not homework. And no, you can't eval("var") to get the value of the `var` parameter.

Comment: If this isn't homework, then why the weird restrictions on what variables may be accessed, or what functions may be used? State your needs clearly.

Comment: You _may_ use eval, it's just that you _CAN'T_ use eval as it won't help.

Comment: To add to that, there is one __one__ restriction, not multiple restrictions. The one restriction is that you can't access `arguments`.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of one way to achieve this and even that one way relies on both - deprecated `callee.caller` and an already fixed FF peculiarity of `eval` being able to execute code in a context of a specified function.

What's interesting is that I think `eval` was "fixed" before `function({...}){}` extension was introduced, but I'm not totally sure.

I reduced test case slightly, but preserving an actual idea, of course.

I first tried accessing `arguments` off of a caller itself, but it looks like `<fn>.arguments` references same object as `arguments` within function context; `null`ing arguments object essentially destroyed object referred to by `arguments` property as well.

I also thought about evaling stack string from an error object (to get `test` values), but that would not solve anything, as test values are objects, not primitives.

```
(function () {
  function mySolution () {
    var test = arguments = null;
    return eval('test', (function(){ return arguments.callee.caller; })());
  };
  var test = {
    "var"   : {},
    "this"  : {},
    "function": {},
    "if"    : {},
    "return"  : {},
    "true"  : {}
  },
  results = mySolution(test),
  pass = true;

  for (var prop in test)
    if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        if (results[prop] !== test[prop])
            pass = false;

  alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
})();
```

Comment: `arguments.callee.caller` isn't deprecated last I checked, just non-standard. The deprecated thing is `arguments.caller`. Your solution doesn't solve the challenge that is stated in my question though. My question involves actually getting the values of the formal parameters (ie. `function(a){return a}` gets the `a` formal parameter).

Comment: Also, please test your solution as it actually doesn't work in non-fixed or fixed JS engines. Given `someFunction` (which declares a private variable, `a`), eval("a", someFunction) doesn't return the private variable, "a". It returns `someFunction.a` if the property exists.

Comment: It does work and, yes, I did test it. Which "non-fixed or fixed JS engines" are you talking about? I haven't seen implementations that return `someFunction.a` when calling `eval('a', someFunction)`, so I don't know where you're getting it from. Mozilla, on the other hand, had extension to evaluate code in a scope of a given function (i.e. using function's internal [[Scope]]) See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=442333.

Comment: Well you still are missing the point. Even if this does solve it, I nulled `test` for a reason, so you don't access it. If your solution works with destructuring assignment ({a,b,c}) in the arguments, I will make this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found a better answer, this time. (I have to admit that I got the general idea from kangax's answer, though). Tested PASS in FF 3.0.13:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
(function () {
    function mySolution ({
        var,
        this,
        function,
        if,
        return,
        true
    }) {
        // prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
        var test = arguments = null,

        args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return', 'true'],
        results = {};

        // put your solution here
        var o = eval('arguments', mySolution)[0];
        for(var prop in o) {
         results[prop] = o[prop];
        }

        return results;
    };
    var test = {
        "var"     : {},
        "this"    : {},
        "function": {},
        "if"      : {},
        "return"  : {},
        "true"    : {}
    },
    results = mySolution(test),
    pass = true;

    for (var prop in test)
        if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                if (results[prop] !== test[prop])
                        pass = false;

    alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL")
}());

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Put the body of your page below this line -->

<!-- Put the body of your page above this line -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why this works... it seems like maybe the eval() function has a special case for the 'arguments' property, where it doesn't use the same property that is used within the method itself? Or maybe the "arguments" being assigned the value "null" is actually not the method arguments array?

Comment: I tested in firefox 3.5.2 and it doesnt works "TypeError: eval('arguments', mySolution) is null"

Comment: This does seem like the kind of thing that could be a bug in FF, fixed in a later version =(

Comment: As I already explained, this was a rather serious security hole in Mozilla (being able to evaluate string in a scope of arbitrary function). 3.0.13 still "works" (as RMorrisey noted), but 3.5 already doesn't. I think they fixed it shortly after 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt #3; again, tested PASS in FF 3.0.13

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
(function () {
    function mySolution ({
        var,
        this,
        function,
        if,
        return,
        true
    }) {
        // prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
        var test = arguments = null,

        args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return', 'true'],
        results = {};

        // put your solution here
        var o = mySolution[0];
        for (var prop in o) {
           results[prop] = o[prop];
        }

        return results;
    };
    var test = {
        "var"     : {},
        "this"    : {},
        "function": {},
        "if"      : {},
        "return"  : {},
        "true"    : {}
    },
    results = mySolution(test),
    pass = true;

    for (var prop in test)
        if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                if (results[prop] !== test[prop])
                        pass = false;

    alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL")
}());

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Put the body of your page below this line -->

<!-- Put the body of your page above this line -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried lots of ways. Kind of given up. But if you can't break the system, change the system.
MY solution:

```
(function () {
    function mySolution ({
        var,
        this,
        function,
        if,
        return,
        true
    }) {
        // prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
        var test = arguments = null,

        args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return', 'true'],
        results = {};

        // put your solution here
/********** MY SOLUTION STARTS ******************/
        return null;
    }
    function mySolution ({
        var,
        this,
        function,
        if,
        return,
        true
    }) {
        // new function does not prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
        //var test = arguments = null,

        args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return', 'true'],
        results = {};
        for(var i =0; i < args.length; i++) {
            results[args[i]] = arguments[0][args[i]];
        }
/********** MY SOLUTION ENDS ******************/
        return results;
    };
    var test = {
        "var"     : {},
        "this"    : {},
        "function": {},
        "if"      : {},
        "return"  : {},
        "true"    : {}
    },
    results = mySolution(test),
    pass = true;

    for (var prop in test)
        if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                if (results[prop] !== test[prop])
                        pass = false;

    alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL")
}());
```

Comment: Well of course `arguments[0]` has the object but the whole purpose of the challenge is to see if you can get the invalid parameters without replicating the deconstruction.

Comment: hey can you give a hint on how to go about solving this!!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    function mySolution ({ var, this, function, if, return, true }) {
    // prohbit reference to arguments and the test object
    var test = arguments = null, args = ['var', 'this', 'function', 'if', 'return','true'], results = {};
    //LAME...
    };
    mySolution=function(a){var results=a;
    //LAME...
    return results;
};
var test = {
      "var" : {},
      "this" : {},
      "function": {},
      "if" : {},
      "return" : {},
      "true" : {} }, results = mySolution(test), pass = true;
 for (var prop in test)
        if (test.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            if (results[prop] !== test[prop]) pass = false;
 alert(pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL") }());
```